# Динамические диалоги

Tags: java, android

Хочу реализовать систему, позволяющую удобно (для меня) оперировать с диалогами. Принцип прост: в отдельном классе я создаю методы, каждый из которых отвечает за конкретный диалог. На выходе метод имеет целое число (integer), которое указывает на номер нажатой в AlertDialog кнопки. Это число передается обратно в тот метод, из которого я вызывал свой DialogManager. Однако у меня возникли некоторые проблемы с преобразованием типов. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно?

Класс, в котором я вызываю диалог:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    int result = DialogManager.showDialogSearchError();
    if(result == 0){ // вернем пользователя в прежнюю активность
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish(); // for normal job of button 'back'
    }
}
```

Сам DialogManager:

```
public class DialogManager extends AppCompatActivity{

private static Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static int showDialogSearchError() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Произошла ошибка")
            .setMessage("К сожалению, произошла ошибка во время выполнения..")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_cat)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("ОК, иду на кухню",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

    return 1; // здесь всего одна кнопка есть, поэтому на выходе только единица
}
```

В логах (LogCat) я получаю предупреждения:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
```

Я думаю остальная часть логов не требуется...

Comment: в `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)` у вас `context` = `null`, так как `onCreate` для его инициализации не вызван. Ну и показывать в одной активности диалог с контекстом другой - плохая практика. Проще расширтесь от `DialogFragment`. Как есть, могу только предложить передавать в функцию контекст текущей активности на вызове

Comment: Простите, а как правильно произвести это расширение? Можно, пожалуйста, пример? Это для каждого диалога еще свой класс делать нужно будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы у вас был отдельный класс для диалогов, лучше делать это через `DialogFragment`:

```
public class DialogCustom extends DialogFragment { 
    public static final String TYPE = "type"; 
    public static final String DATA = "data"; 

    //идентификаторы разных диалогов
    public static final int EXIT = 1; 
    public static final int HELP = 2;     

// интерфэйс для обратной связи из диалога
    private DialogCallback dialogCallback;     

public interface DialogCallback { 
    void dialogCallback(int result, String resultString); //любые ваши переменные
} 

//Два разных метода для приёма разных параметров (по потребности можно больше)
public static DialogCustom newInstance(int type) { 
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
    args.putInt(TYPE, type); 
    DialogCustom fragment = new DialogCustom(); 
    fragment.setArguments(args); 
    return fragment; 
} 

public static DialogCustom newInstance(int type, String data) { 
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
    args.putInt(TYPE, type); 
    args.putInt(DATA, data); 
    DialogCustom fragment = new DialogCustom(); 
    fragment.setArguments(args); 
    return fragment; 
}
//выбор нужного диалога
@NonNull 
@Override 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    switch (getArguments().getInt(TYPE)) { 
        case EXIT: 
            return exitDialog(); 
        case HELP: 
            return helpDialog(); 
    } 
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState); 
}
//пример диалога
private Dialog exitDialog() { 
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
    final View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_exit, null, false); 
    adb.setView(v); 
    v.findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
          //ваш код
        } 
    }); 
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message)).setText("ваш текст");
    Dialog dialog = adb.create(); 
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); 
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    return dialog; 
}

//---Инциализация колбэка-— 
@TargetApi(23) 
@Override 
public void onAttach(Context context) { 
    super.onAttach(context); 
    try { 
        dialogCallback = (DialogCallback) context; 
    } catch (ClassCastException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

"deprecation" 
@Override 
public void onAttach(Activity activity) { 
    super.onAttach(activity); 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) { 
        try { 
            dialogCallback = (DialogCallback) activity; 
        } catch (ClassCastException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}

@Override 
public void onDetach() { 
    super.onDetach(); 
    if (dialogCallback != null) dialogCallback = null; 
}
}
```

**Использование.** В нужном месте вызвать

```
DialogCustom.newInstance(DialogCustom.HELP,"help")
     .show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
```

или

```
DialogCustom.newInstance(DialogCustom.EXIT)
     .show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
```

или еще какой вам нужно (по собственному `id`).

Если надо вернуть из диалога результаты, в нужном его месте используем `interface`:

```
dialogCallback.dialogCallback(1,"success");
```

Возвращать можно не только `String`, а любой тип/типы, какой укажите в интерфейсе

Comment: Прошу прощения, что не сразу смог попробовать этот метод. А этот диалог так и должен появляться в другой активности/фрагменте? (я не знаю как их различить...)

Comment: Это фрагмент, который будет появляться в контексте текущей активности

Comment: Простите, еще одно, я не понял куда вставлять dialogCallback.dialogCallback(1,"success"). И что означает первый dialogCallback, а что второй? А также в скобках указано 1 и success. Я так полагаю это два возвращаемых значения типа int и string?

Comment: Если вам надо передать данные из диалога назад в активность (частая потребность), то в том месте, где вы хотите данные передать. Данные могут быть любыми и любых типов, 1 и "success" приведены для примера.